# Create Client side socket (Winsock, MQL5, MT5) and Server side Socket using (NodeJS + Socket.io)

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, mql5, metatrader5

I have a windows server 2016 and I am trying to send data from Meta Trader 5 using EA to the specific port (777) in localhost and I am using NodeJS, Socket.io on the other hand to capture that data.

I would like to pass data from MT5 to a localhost:some_port. I have never worked with sockets (client-server) for sending and receiving of data between two applications or codebase.

Here, Web(NodeJS application acting as a Server side) and MT5(as Client Side).

### NodeJS application - Creates Server and looks for client connection

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var express = require('express');

io.on('connection', function(socket) {  
  console.log("new user connected");

  //sends test data on creating a connection
  socket.emit('live-data', 'test data');
});

app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js')); // redirect bootstrap JS
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/jquery/dist')); // redirect JS jQuery
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css')); // redirect CSS bootstrap

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

http.listen(777, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:777');
});
```

### Client Side

```
/* ###################################################################

Example socket client.
Code can be used as both MQ4 and MQ5 (on both 32-bit and 64-bit MT5)

Simply sends each new tick to the server, as a CRLF-terminated 
message. The example server then writes these to its Experts log.

################################################################### */


#property strict

// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// Include socket library
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <socket-library-mt4-mt5.mqh>


// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// EA user inputs
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

input string   Hostname = "localhost";    // Server hostname or IP address
input ushort   ServerPort = 777;        // Server port


// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// Global variables and constants
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

ClientSocket * glbClientSocket = NULL;

// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// Initialisation (no action required)
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

void OnInit() {}


// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// Termination - free the client socket, if created
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

void OnDeinit(const int reason)
{
   if (glbClientSocket) {
      delete glbClientSocket;
      glbClientSocket = NULL;
   }
}


// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// Tick handling - set up a connection, if none already active,
// and send the current price quote
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

void OnTick()
{
   if (!glbClientSocket) {
      glbClientSocket = new ClientSocket(Hostname, ServerPort);
      if (glbClientSocket.IsSocketConnected()) {
         Print("Client connection succeeded");
      } else {
         Print("Client connection failed");
      }
  }

   if (glbClientSocket.IsSocketConnected()) {
      // Send the current price as a CRLF-terminated message
      string strMsg = Symbol() + "," + DoubleToString(SymbolInfoDouble(Symbol(), SYMBOL_BID), 6) + "," + DoubleToString(SymbolInfoDouble(Symbol(), SYMBOL_ASK), 6) + "\r\n";
      glbClientSocket.Send(strMsg);

   } else {
      // Either the connection above failed, or the socket has been closed since an earlier
      // connection. We handle this in the next block of code...
   }

   // If the socket is closed, destroy it, and attempt a new connection
   // on the next call to OnTick()
   if (!glbClientSocket.IsSocketConnected()) {
      // Destroy the server socket. A new connection
      // will be attempted on the next tick
      Print("Client disconnected. Will retry.");
      delete glbClientSocket;
      glbClientSocket = NULL;
   }
}
```

### Update

[image]

I keep getting above message. and I dont see any data sent to the Nodejs Socket.

Comment: You might want to edit your question a bit, since you're not actually asking anything.
Aside from that, why socket.io ? WebSocket really are a standard now, socket.io isn't really easier to use and adds overhead.

Comment: @Ealhad I will edit my question, but I am looking to send data from mt5 to localhost:port. I am not coming from a background of mql5 or aspnet or c#. Can you tell me what technologies I should I use?

Comment: I don't know this tech stack either, but from what I understand these aren't WebSockets at all, just regular sockets. So in node you should use [net](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html).

Comment: @Ealhad ok this information you shared does help. I will try to use net.and see the outcome.

Comment: @Ealhad it works, net did the trick :) Thanks alot, I have been trying to figure out this for days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using sockets on one side, and WebSockets on the other, and the two are different things.

In node, you should use [net](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html), which is part of the standard library.